# Java ArrayList mixed object types, can't access method

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm using an ArrayList that needs to contain different object types, and I can't access the object methods, unless the ArrayList is set to one specific type. How should I do this? And if there's a better solution (I need to use a linked list kind of data structure), what would I be better off using?

The following code is an example code to show what I mean.
This code works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    arr.add(new Integer(3));
    arr.get(0).floatValue();
}
```

This doesn't work :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Object> arr = new ArrayList<Object>();
    arr.add(new Integer(3));
    arr.get(0).floatValue();
}
```

Comment: Yes that does not work because the get returns you a reference to an Object, therefore you can only call methods of Object.

What different classes do you have to store in the list?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you'd added a string reference (say) to the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get` method in the second example will return a Object (as in java.lang.Object) and this doesn't have a `floatValue()` method.

You could solve this by casting the returned Object:

```
     ((Integer) arr.get(0)).floatValue();
```

This will get you an `unchecked cast` warning in most IDEs. So the first example should be preferred unless you want to check each Object for the right type.

Answer (score 0):

`arr.get(0)` will return a reference of type `Object` and not `Integer`. You get compile-time error because `Object` class does not have a method named `floatValue()`.

To resolve this, you need to add a cast `(Integer)` before calling the `floatValue()` method on the object.

Something like this:

```
((Integer) arr.get(0)).floatValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second code use a cast like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
ArrayList<Object> arr = new ArrayList<Object>();
arr.add(new Integer(3));
((Integer)arr.get(0)).floatValue();
}
```

Moreover if you are not sure an entry is of a specific type then check it using `instanceof` like:

```
if(arr.get(0) instanceof Integer)
{
((Integer)arr.get(0)).floatValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store them as  objects and then cast them when you retrieve each one.This is kinda error likely and i woud not recommend you to do that.Bud surelly you can do it like this.Just remember the order and what type you put in there

Comment: if he don't remember the order he can always test it with `instanceof`

Comment: Ofcourse he can.Bud i still dont think this is a good design to go for.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type, you can simply cast it:

```
((Integer) arr.get(0)).floatValue();
```

If the `Object` is not an Integer, you will get a `ClassCastException`.